# Laravel migrations/db:seed super slow

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-connection

I recently upgraded from my old Windows computer into a gen. 4 I7 Ubuntu 15.04

Runs like a dream, well...Except that any Laravel artisan command that touch the database takes a million years to complete, while my old computer performed any of those commands in seconds.

The major difference is that instead of XAMPP I'm running MySQL as a local service.

Also in my old computer I could see how migrations slowly showed on screen as they appear to be processed while now, it takes like 2~5 minutes and when done the whole migration list is shown at once.
This could indicate a bottle neck of sort somewhere.

Somewhere around the internet someone said to use ***'127.0.0.1'*** instead of ***'localhost'*** because of DSN resolution. Didn't solve it.

To make sure that's not the issue i ran

```
    $time = microtime(true);

    //also with host=127.0.0.1
    new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=some_db", "username", "password");

    //some simple queries here...

    //yielded similar marginal times
    echo microtime(true) - $time;
```

~halp

---

**Edit**

I collected the running times for each query from the framework, I have **LOTS** of migrations, analyzing the data I found there's nothing insanely slow (like a query running for a minute).

[Here's a link with the data](http://pastebin.com/ytGxJWaK). Actual queries were ommited in favor of my employer.

Although there's many queries running for a second or longer, the slowest, `number 221` takes a whoping 3.5 seconds.

I have around a hundred migrations(I know) but here's the thing, if each migration took a second I'd be waiting around a minute and a half to migrate, but it often takes from 4 to 5 minutes.

As suggested by oliverpool, I did some profiling by replaying queries on the mysql via terminal, but *I never had to wait longer than a second* with the average query taking around thenth of a second.

Here is a pic of the profiling for the slowest query (3.5secs in migration, not close to a second in the pic)

[image]

Maybe this points towards the connection? By the way **the slow query log is empty** after running the migrations.

Also, I'm using laravel 5 now and the behaviour is the same. I dont know how to trouble shoot connection so I guess some googling is in order, any suggestions are welcome.

**Thanks in advance**.

Comment: Can you run some queries in the mysql client to make sure it isn't MySQL that is slow. Also, run `php -v` to make sure it isn't PHP that is slow.

Comment: Are you sure than your DB config of Laravel is correct? Maybe you can do some profiling, to see which Queries are executed by artisan, and replay them.

Comment: Perhaps your MySQL configuration? Could there be an inefficient seed in the code?

Comment: please check your old windows mysql.ini alongside the new ubuntu mysql.ini. they should have different configurations. Check buffer sizes .. these articles might help http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-parameters.html

Comment: Might actually be `php-cli` related, since you say that mysql profiling returned optimum time results. I'd suggest you compare the time execution of a php script from the console and browser. `php -q test.php` http://pastebin.com/AwNJk33n In my case, cli result is about `0.076` and web result is about `0.009`

Comment: run migrations for 24h then run mysqltuner and fix up your my.cnf default ubuntu config is crap.  I've had exactly the same issue stuff ran fine on wamp on windows swapped to linux and it was dog slow for certain work.  In my case it was filehandles flags on the kernel and not enough buffers assigned to innodb so it was doing it all in disk IO rather than ram.

Comment: I'll be trying all of those suggestions in a couple hours. It'd be nice if you can make your suggestions into answers so I can award the bounty on the one who fixed the issue (or the best one if none). Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

In this case, I think that the buffer pool size increment is required. Set the following:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_io_capacity = 2000
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
```

Answer (score -2):

**if you  are using MySQL 8**

in my case, the problem was MySQL 8 slower `insert` speed which occurred
after updating MySQL 5.7 to 8

A difference between 5.7 and 8.0 is that binary logging (to be used for replication and PITR) is on by default in MySQL 8.0. To run without binary logging in 8.0

the quick fix of this problem is to start your MySQL server with `--disable-log-bin`

or you can write below codes in your my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
skip-log-bin
```

for more information, please visit

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216352/inserts-in-mysql-8-are-slower-than-inserts-in-mysql-5-7?newreg=fe2b7682e8314f07a785ddc9a8ffbdce

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227742/extreme-performance-loss-due-to-moving-from-mysql-5-7-23-to-mysql-8-0-status-c

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26954068)

Comment: Please explain further how this is related to the question. MySQL 8 was first released nearly three years after this question has been posted

Comment: @NicoHaase I updated my answer again,  I hope this be ok now