# Localhost MySQL PHP Database Migration Slow Performance Compared To Virtualhost Homestead

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, server, localhost

[VIRTUAL HOST] Laravel Homestead database migration are so much faster than my [LOCALHOST] Laravel Valet / Vessel / XAMPP /?

Can anyone explain why? Or is there a way to enhance my localhosts speed?

Comment: How big is the difference?

Comment: Laravel Homestead using Virtualbox = 8 seconds, Laravel Valet using localhost = 117 seconds

Comment: have you disabled the cli php xdebug?

Comment: I have run this command to disable xdebug sudo phpdismod -s cli xdebug

Comment: what OS are you using ?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 Linux

Comment: it looks like you've got debugbar installed ?

Comment: what kind of debugbar?

Comment: Maybe it's becsause the buffer size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706146/laravel-migrations-dbseed-super-slow

Comment: How many tables and migrations do you have to notice the difference ?

Comment: @MahmoudAbdALKareem I have more than 40 tables. the difference when i perform this command "php artisan migrate:fresh --seed" 

Laravel Homestead using Virtualbox = 8 seconds, Laravel Valet using localhost = 117 seconds

Comment: I'm trying to investigate that, It may related to some configurations of the homestead that causes this big difference.

Comment: I have tried copying the process in php and mysql related stuff in here https://github.com/laravel/settler/blob/master/scripts/provision.sh

Comment: also I have tried it in my computer localhost that uses ssd and the result is around 15secs. Homestead is still faster by 7 seconds.

Comment: tried and tested it. Virtualhost is marginally faster. Let's wait till some server pro commented on this.

Comment: How much RAM in each?  What value for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` in each?

Comment: I don't really know how to know the innodb_buffer_pool_size of each but they should be the same because I have not modified mysql config after installation.

Comment: have check homestead php version and your local php version ?

Comment: this must be related to development environment make sure that your php version are same this is the first check point in the investigation

Comment: use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost when connecting to mysql through php on windows

Comment: Are you sure that the MySQL settings are equal? If no, please show us them from Vagrant and localhost.

Comment: I noticed that this happens only when my localhost uses a standard drive. 

The seeding is even faster than homestead on a standard drive when using an SSD at localhost. 

So I'm assuming that VirtualBox somehow speeds up the drive of the homestead box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VM image is loaded into memory, which would account for the speed difference. In memory usage at the Activity Monitor, VBoxHeadless takes up 1.4G with Laravel Homestead. This is probably the reason why Laravel Homestead is faster than localhost.

Answer (score -1):

For example if you're running xampp on Windows, this tool is not optimized for a better performance.

Always a Linux platform runs better open source tools.

For example you can see on Ubuntu only runs services you determine for your job, such as: apache, mysql deamon, etc. and obviusly you can access the root configuration of Apache meanwhile on a tool like Xampp you only install and don't know whatexaclty is ocurring behind escenes.

I hope my response be useful for you.