# Php Artisan migrate is super Slow?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel, I am using the 5.7 version, I am following a course that looks very good but I created my database on mysql and then I tried to run the command - php artisan migrate - and it took so long, I get bored everytime and I cancel it, there must be a better solution because it is very very slow, the man I am following his course get a response quickly as do many others, is there any solution out there that can help me move faster, am I missing something ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you using mysql?

Comment: @cecilmerrelakabringrainfire yes .. I am using mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel migrations/db:seed super slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706146/laravel-migrations-dbseed-super-slow)

Comment: see this answer if you are using mysql 8 https://stackoverflow.com/a/63451673/10053470

Answer (score 1):

A lot of depends on your migrations but also on your server. Assuming you are using localhost server speed shouldn't affect, so you should take a look at migrations.

Again, assuming you just create new tables migrations should be quick, but when you alter schema or add some data in loops or run some queries then yes, they might be slow if you don't have optimized code but this is reason of code itself and not in general migrations.

Comment: Well I didnt do any of that, I didnt write a lot of code, just few lines because I am just learning, so  as you have said, this has to be quick but it is slow as hell..

Answer (score 1):

This must most likely be a peculiar problem on your server. Quickly restart your server and try again. If it persists, go on to restart your PC.

Laravel migrations are usually very fast, even when very bulky. So if this problem persists even after restarting your server and even the PC, then you will have to conduct a quick investigation to know what the cause is.

Comment out all the lines of code in the create method's callback. Then try running the migration. This should be fast. Go on to add the commented lines one after the other why testing, you should see which line of code is slowing you.

Comment: I will try to do that Sir

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using mysql, try increasing your buffer pool size like the following.

```
[mysqld]
innodb_io_capacity = 2000
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
```

Comment: My problem is solved, I made a stupid error, sorry for wasting your time, it was all my fault, I ma using mamp and instead of using 8889 as DB_PORT I used 8888 as a value, I am really sorry

Comment: Tried this. Still slow. =(

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem and I tried many techniques but it didn't work for me.

This problem appears when I was using MySQL. I uninstalled MySQL and I use MariaDB; it's super fast now.

I noticed this because I use MariaDB in my office device, while very slow migration was in my home device. Maybe there are configurations to enhance migrations on MySQL but I did my best without results so I migrated to MariaDB.