# Laravel migrations slow using MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

My migrations are slow when using MySQL. I timed the differences between `sqlite` and `mysql` and ended up with this:

**mysql**

> php artisan migrate:fresh  0,17s user 0,06s system 3% cpu 6,043 total

**sqlite**

> php artisan migrate:fresh  0,16s user 0,08s system 90% cpu 0,268 total

Except for the big time difference, `mysql` seems to use very little CPU. So I added [these settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32396652/5191800) to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and restarted the mysql service but that didn't affect the speed nor the cpu %.

I also tried copying *only* the migration-files to a new laravel project, and experienced the same result. I am using *homestead* with *VirtualBox* on a macOS Mojave. I have about 20 migrations and they are pretty small in terms of size. Running the migrations on my production server, they take less than 1 second.

Why are my migrations taking unexpectedly long when using MySQL?

Comment: Connecting to MySQL on my machine (no vm) takes the response time down to 1s.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using mysql outside of the VM.